# How can get the count of Active live actors?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

I'm using akka cluster sharding 2.5.23. For my case i want to know the current live active actors count.I have read many articles saying use Lightbend telemetry which is paid.And Cinnamonor or kamon which i don't need that much of metrics.I only need to know current active actors. Any way to achieve this easy?

Comment: there is no direct way according to my knowledge. but you can use akka cluster http management to find it out indirectly. link https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/cluster-http-management.html

Comment: @John that won't provide that.  Note that "members" refers to `ActorSystem`s in the cluster.

Comment: @LeviRamsey, yes it is possible. I used that. shard regions -> shardIds -> numEntities . akka 2.6.x

Comment: That will just tell you the number of sharded entities which are currently incarnate, which, sure, is a lower bound on number of actors, but beyond that tells you nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i'm using ActorCluster sharding with Remember entities as ddata,All the entityActors are remembered in distributed way.
We have **GetClusterShardingStats** util get the sharding stats in that we will have the current shard count and actors count in that Cluster.

```
GetClusterShardingStats stats = new ShardRegion.GetClusterShardingStats(FiniteDuration.create(25000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
final Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(25);
                Future<Object> ack = Patterns.ask(region, stats, timeout).toCompletableFuture();
                ClusterShardingStats ss = (ClusterShardingStats) ack.get(25000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

By iterating this ClusterShardingStats we can get the current Live Shard Count and Actors in that Shard count even with Node wise count.